# phonegap : html5 database wiped on os update or sync

Tags: html, cordova, sqlite

I've created a phonegap app that uses html5 database for storage. 
Updating the os or in some cases syncing the phone wipes the database. Not good, obviously.

Why does this happen, and how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Which storage medium? local storage, indexedDB, sqllite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ran into this problem with the iOS 5.1 upgrade.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-347?focusedCommentId=13261034&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13261034

It's been fixed in release 1.7.0.

Comment: So is this a phonegap issue or an iOS issue, who's the culprit?